# How big is a single RAM cell?

Tags: c, memory, ram

I am studying on my own how the PC works and I can't understand one thing. A 32 or 64 bit processor differs for its ability to allocate 2 ^ 32 or 2 ^ 64 addresses for the cells of the RAM. What I do not understand is how big a single cell is. Is a single cell big 32 or 64 bit or it is not related with the architecture of the CPU? Thanks so much and sorry for the poor english.

Comment: On X86 memory is byte addressed, so the memory cells are byte sized.

Comment: As @DanD. said, the 32/64-bit refers to the size of the address used to refer to a single byte. Note that in some cases, like using the Jvm, as you switch from 32- to 64-bit addressing, you actually [lose available memory](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/35gb-heap-less-32gb-java-jvm-memory-oddities/) (as the memory required to store pointer addresses doubles)

Comment: A single cell is one bit. Needs 10...100 nm squared. plus some space for the logic to address it.

Comment: It is much more convoluted than that, processors don't directly read from RAM anymore, they read from their caches.  Typical RAM accesses happen 64 bits at a time (8 bytes), regardless of the architecture.  A 64-bit processor currently can access 2 ^ 40 bytes of RAM.  A RAM chip is organized as a grid with rows and columns, an entire column is accessed at the same time.  Ask questions about it at electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

the size of RAM cell is not related with CPU architecture, it probably involves of a couple of  (2 or 3) transistors. so its size probably be at a couple of  nanometers squared (raw). if you count in the circuit gate clothing stuff, probably more.

the CPU architecture gives the ability to access these cells. like keys to doors, so they are independent.

Answer (score 2):

RAM cell size has nothing to CPU. the only thing that is CPU related is how CPU reads from RAM. a 32 bit CPU with 32 bit ram bus can read 4 bytes from ram at once while a 64 bit cpu with 64 bit ram bus can read 8 bytes at once.

Comment: Multiple bytes at once, but only *efficiently* (and on some CPUs, **only**) when the first byte address is correctly aligned to a multiple of the bus size.